# Read (little endian) hex pair that represents a byte in python

Tags: python

What is the right way of reading my hexstring = '40040000' by "little endian" way in python. The result I am expecting is 440h.

Comment: How are you trying to read the string? What result are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what format you want the result to be in. You could use [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#struct-alignment) and [`binascii`](http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html) together to convert it to an int.

```
>>> struct.unpack('<L', binascii.unhexlify('40040000'))
(1088,)
```

Which is the same as 440h:

```
>>> hex(struct.unpack('<L', binascii.unhexlify('40040000'))[0])
'0x440'
```

Comment: Thank you very much senderle. i didn't know it's that simple. This forum really helps. Kind regards :-)